# Finding characteristic polynomial and invariant subspaces of a rank 1 transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm new to this website and I'm really not familiar with the mathJax language so please excuse me for the messy post. Here are the questions I'm having troubles with:

(1)
Let A a nxn matrix over field F which has a rank of 1 (rank(A) = 1).
Prove that the charasteristic polynomial of A is P(λ) = λ^n - tr(A)λ^(n - 1), and find the minimal polynomial of A.

(2)
Let T:F^n → F^n a linear transformation which is defined by Tv = Av for every v ∈ F^n, while A is the matrix from the first question.
Prove that for every 1 ≤ k ≤ n - 1 there is a subspace of F^n from dimension k which is T-invariant.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick mathjax tutorial. You should also explain at what point of these exercises you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider $e_1,...,e_{n-1}$ a base of $Ker(T)$ and $e_n$ such that $e_1,...,e_n$ is a base of $F^n$. Write the matrix in this basis and develop the determinant of $(\lambda -A)$ relatively to the last column.

For $2$ use the fact that $dim Ker(T)=n-1$

Comment: OK so if I understand this correctly since $dimKer(T)=n-1$ then there are $n-1$ eigenvalues whom value is $0$. We also know that the trace of similar matrices is the same, so the remaining eigenvalue is $tr(A)$ which leads us to the given characteristic polynomial. The minimal polynomial is $M(t)=t(t-tr(A))$ since it should be made of unique eigenvalues. For the second question, I think that any subspace made of the vectors $e_1,...,e_{n-1}$ will do since they are a part of the kernel which is an invariant-subspace by itself, no?